# Search FB User with Picture

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fb-graph

I want to search FB Users with a profile picture. I have a picture and i want to compare it and find people matching with their profile picture.

i have tried FBGraphapi search section but it has search users with name only. is there any option to search with picture?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is not supported. Perhaps use Google's "Search by image" search. Do you have a list of Facebook users who the picture may belong to? If you do you can iterate through them and match them to the image at `graph.facebook.com/{user_id}/picture`

Comment: google image search is not a good option as i am trying to search general users of facebook from the image. yes i can look for friends list and then compare but i am first trying to get the general users if thats not possible then will go for friends..